# Python Text Document Translation Comparison

Tags: python, for-loop, compare

Fairly simple question. I'm trying to create a "translation comparison" program that reads and compares two documents and then returns every word that isn't in the other document. This is for a beginner class, so I'm trying to avoid using obscure internal methods, even if that means less efficient code. This is what I have so far...

```
def translation_comparison():
   import re
   file1 = open("Desktop/file1.txt","r")
   file2 = open("Desktop/file2.txt","r")
   text1 = file1.read()
   text2 = file2.read()
   text1 = re.findall(r'\w+',text1)
   text2 = re.findall(r'\w+',text2)
   for item in text2:
       if item not in text1:
           return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this

```
#######Test data
#file1.txt = this is a test
#file2.txt = this a test
#results#
#is

def translation_comparison():
    with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f1:
        f1 = f1.read().split()
    with open("file2.txt", 'r') as f2:
        f2 = f2.read().split()

    for word in f1:
        if word not in f2:
            print(word)


translation_comparison()
```

also it is good practice to use

```
with open("file1.txt", 'r') as f1:
        f1 =f1.read().split()
```

because when using with to open up files it will close the file when you're not using it.  Python is pretty good at releasing and managing memory but it is always good habit to make sure you release it or call

```
file1.close()
```

when you are done.

Comment: Note, this will work for small files, but the larger the file the longer it will take.  for loops in python function at c speed, but that doesn't mean it won't take forever in a large file.  This was just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Thanks..this is helpful. The only problem is that both examples only return the first instance, rather than all instances, where a word isn't in the other text document.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it. Now it will just print is.

Comment: One thing I thought about today, the method above work, but it will append all instances of a word not found.  The best way to fix that is the convert the list that is created into a set.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want word-by-word comparisons, like `a b c` against `b a c` would return both `a` and `b`, then `b` and `a` (as opposed to `None` as in your original code)

```
import string
import itertools

class FileExhausted(Exception): pass

def read_by_word(file):
    def read_word():
        while True:
            l = file.read(1)
            if l:
                if l in string.whitespace:
                    break
                yield l
            else:
                raise FileExhausted

    while True:
        this_word_gen = read_word()
        try:
            this_word = "".join(this_word_gen)
        except FileExhausted:
            break
        else:
            if this_word:
                yield this_word

def translation_comparison():
    with open("file1.txt") as file1, open("file2.txt") as file2:
        words1 = read_by_word(file1)
        words2 = read_by_word(file2)

        for (word1, word2) in itertools.zip_longest(words1, words2, fillvalue=None):
            if word1 != word2:
                yield (word1, word2)
```